# Why does $\chi_{(n,n+1)}$ converge pointwise to the zero function?

Tags: real-analysis, characteristic-functions, pointwise-convergence

Let $g_n=\chi_{(n,n+1)}$ where $\chi$ is the characteristic function of the interval in the subscript. It is given as an example in 4.3 of Real Analysis by Royden and Fitzpatrick that $g_n$ converges pointwise to $g=0$. I don't really understand why though. Is it simply using the below logic? If so, can someone expound on why $\chi_{(\infty,\infty)}=0$. Thanks!

$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} g_n(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \chi_{(n,n+1)} = \chi_{(\infty,\infty)}=0  $$

Comment: If $x\in \mathbb{R}$, for $N = \lfloor x \rfloor +1$, one has $\forall n \geqslant N,~g_n(x) = 0$, thus $\left(g_n(x)\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $0$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $x\in\Bbb R$; you want to prove $\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)=0$. But if $n>x$, then $\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)=0$. So, the numbers of the sequence $\bigl(\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)\bigr)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ are all $0$ if $n$ is large enough, and therefore $\lim_{n\to\infty}\chi_{(n,n+1)}(x)=0$.